# Joomla/Wordpress Azure Hosted sites going down randomly and inconsistantly

Tags: php, wordpress, joomla, azure-web-app-service, cleardb

I recently moved 2 websites over to Azure. One was wordpress and one was joomla. I have a monitoring website (24X7) that pings the website every 5 minutes to make sure they are still up. 2 days ago, both went down for about 3 minutes at around the same time. The screenshots just showed a white page. The error was "Unable to connect to the service or the connection was interrupted". Today, just the wordpress site goes down for about 2 minutes with the error "the page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred". At one point both stayed up for 5 days without going down. This problem is so inconsistent and im hoping someone might have some ideas as to how to approach this issue. At this point im thinking it may be a ClearDB which is the MySql database Azure uses. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the MySQL slow query log - most likely you will find the issue there (you will find slow queries at around the same time the websites were down). It might also be a transient network hiccup.

Comment: where is the MySQL slow query log located?

Comment: Typically under /var/lib/mysql